# Using singleSelect but leaving background selections on and retrieving data from an API

Tags: php, jquery, imagemapster

I think I'm pretty close. The idea is to have the background sections turned on according to the data from the API (this one, if you want to try it http://www.propertysolutions.com/api-documentation/code-snippet), and still have the functionality of mouseover and select. 
To get me close I used James' Beatles demo. I'm about there but can't seem to add singleSelect without turning off the background.

```
$(function () {
var inArea,
map = $('#beatlesIMG'),

    single_opts = {
        fillColor: '000000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: 'ff0000',
        strokeWidth: 2
    },
    all_opts = {
        fillColor: 'ffffff',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        stroke: true,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeColor: 'ffffff'
    },
    initial_opts = {
        mapKey: 'data-name'
    };
opts = $.extend({}, all_opts, initial_opts, single_opts);

map.mapster('unbind')
    .mapster(opts)
map.mapster('set_options', all_opts)
    .mapster('set', true, 'all')
    .mapster('set_options', single_opts);
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SpudLogic/w4w8U/4/

Would love to hear some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me

```
$(function ()
{
var basic_opts = {
    mapKey: 'data-key1',
    fill: true,
    fillColor: '9A7611',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    singleSelect: true
};

var initial_opts = $.extend({},basic_opts, 
    { 
        staticState: true,
        fill: true,
        fillColor: 'F9461C',
        stroke: false
    });
$('#floorplan').mapster(initial_opts)
.mapster('snapshot')
.mapster('rebind',basic_opts );

});
```